# Routes stopped working when upgrading Rails 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 3.1. My application worked fine in Rails 3.0 but when I bumped it up to Rails 3.1.4, all my url helpers broke!

After Googling like a mad man the past 2 days, I have given up and the time has come to seek help. I don't believe the problem is with my routes.rb file but something more on the view/helper side.

I have the following in my routes.rb:

```
resources :sessions
```

In my homepage view I have the following link_to, which errors out:

```
<%= link_to "Login", new_session_path %>
```

When I do rake routes, I get the following output, so the path exists:

```
          sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)          {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"index"}
                   POST   /sessions(.:format)          {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}
       new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
      edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"edit"}
           session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"show"}
                   PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"update"}
                   DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
```

When I go to /sessions/new in my browser, the page loads so again, the route exists, but it errors out on a _path based url:

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path, :method => :post do -%>
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `sessions_path' for #<#<Class:0x109cb8900>:0x109cab840>):
```

It has to be something with the url_for helper as the routes do exist. What else should I look for?

UPDATE 1:

I added the following inside application_helper.rb:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Now when I get the following error:

```
In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Isn't that is what I just did?

Update 2:

The following worked as MrYoshiji suggested:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sessions_path
```

Update 3:

I got sessions_path working again by removing some old Rails 2 plugins in vendor directory.

Comment: Maybe crazy to ask but did you restart your server ?

Comment: Yes I did restart my server and got the same results.

Comment: Hmm the /sessions(.:format) seems to respond to GET request, and you ask for POST method. Have you tried with :get ?

Comment: I have tried get with `<%= form_tag sessions_path, :method => :get do -%>` and still getting the "undefined local variable or method error". The routes seem to work, like when I do /sessions/new in the browser. But for some reason the view is losing route/path information. Hope this helps.

Comment: When I change the path to string one '<%= form_tag "/sessions", :method => :post do -%>' the view will render and I can submit the form. It just doesn't like sessions_path. This is happening with all my _path routes. As the navigation on the next page errors out the same way.

Comment: Another update, I have added the following inside my application_helper.rb 'include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers' and now I get a different error 'In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers'. Though isn't that what I just did?

Comment: Can you try `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sessions_path` instead of only `sessions_path` ?

Comment: That is a good suggestion and we are getting somewhere! `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sessions_path` instead of `sessions_path` worked. Though it would be so much work to prepend that to each route.

Comment: Is it doing this for every url helper you try to call?

Comment: Yes it is, every single url helper.

Comment: From where are you trying to use this helper? In app/views/sessions/ ?

Comment: I am using the `<%= form_tag Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sessions_path, :method => :post do -%>` inside of app/views/sessions/new.html.erb.

Comment: I found what the problem was. I had some old rails 2 plugins in my vendor directory, they were causing issues in rails 3.1. I'm happy to have this resolved and thanks for your help MrYoshiji.

Answer (score 0):

Removed some Rails 2 plugins in vendor/plugins did the trick.