# Rails 3.2: Routing helpers in views break locally after other error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.0

When developing locally using Rails 3.2, I periodically receive the following error message:

```
In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

This error is thrown from my views in a very simple `link_to` call, where these routing helpers are automatically included and should not throw such an error. I don't think the error is occurring where it says, but I'll post an example error dump for completeness' sake:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 233ms

ActionView::Template::Error (In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers):
    1: <%= form_tag products_path do %>

  app/views/layouts/_search_banner.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_layouts__search_banner_html_erb___3528929561490713150_70155778060240'
  app/views/pages/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pages_new_html_erb__29715639072237790_70155789748980'
```

Before it appears, I am able to properly view all of my pages; after it appears, the same pages that had just loaded successfully fail with that same error. Once the error appears, the only way to fix it is to exit and restart my local rails server. As soon as I restart my server the error disappears and everything goes back to working normally.

Also, this error only appears locally on my computer - the code is deployed on Heroku and this error has not appeared in months of deployment, and no other team members operating on the same code have seen the error. **EDIT:** other team members operating on the same code **do** see the same error.

Although this error sometimes pops up out of nowhere with no apparent cause, there are a couple of trends I have noticed. It frequently appears immediately after a different error. It also is more likely to appear when the rails server has been idle for some time without loading any pages.

**EDIT:** More Information
Rails version: 3.2.13
Ruby version: 2.0.0

The full stack trace can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/hspinks/c3156fbb770d823bda30)

I achieved the error by writing code to throw an error in an action, sending a request to that action, then attempting to access any other page in the application. Interestingly, the first error that I attempted to use was a division by zero, which did not create the error. Next, I created a Undefined Method for Array[] error, which resulted in the one described here.

**EDIT:** Deprecation Warning for Rails 2.3-style plugins
When I deploy to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins!
Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0.
Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb.
See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.
(called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_175439d1-f385-43bd-bf52-ebcae817e70b/Rakefile:7)
```

This error is thrown in my Rakefile on the line `MyApp::Application.load_tasks`. I do not have any files in my `vendor/plugin` directory.

Comment: also, unlike [other similar SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553326/call-to-expire-fragment-raises-to-use-url-for-you-must-include-routing-helpe?rq=1), I have not switched rails versions recently.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall ruby and rails since this exception occurs only in your local environment? What is the version of ruby? Can you post full trace? For your reference this exception raises here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/url_for.rb

Comment: @peresleguine I added ruby version and full trace to the question.

Comment: @peresleguine I have reinstalled both ruby and rails since this issue first occurred and saw no change. Also, other team members have started seeing the issue, so I know it is not just something with my local environment

Comment: Is there a class in your project that inherits directly from ActionController::Metal?

Comment: Do you have the ruby-debug-ide gem or other old plugins installed? See these two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778995/routes-stopped-working-when-upgrading-rails-3-0-to-3-1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553326/call-to-expire-fragment-raises-to-use-url-for-you-must-include-routing-helpe.

Comment: @peresleguine no class that I'm aware of that inherits directly from ActionController::Metal, unless it comes from one of my gems (unlikely).

Comment: @JamesChen I don't have ruby-debug-ide gem, but I think you may be on the right track with old plugins. When I deploy to Heroku, I get a deprecation warning saying that I have Rails 2.3 style plugins in `vendor/plugins`. My `vendor/plugins` folder is empty, so it must be coming from a gem? The warning was too long to post in a comment, so I'll add it as an edit to the question.

Comment: This might be too much, but can you post your Gemfile so that we can investigate possible gems that could be causing this error

Comment: @TMP I've added the Gemfile to the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/hspinks/c3156fbb770d823bda30) with the traces. We've since upgraded our Gemfile to remove many of these gems as we transition to Rails 4, but I believe this Gemfile reflects the gems that were present around when the error first came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i can see it's an issue with your rails version. see the comments on this resque issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11782#issuecomment-22222166

Comment: We are upgrading to Rails 4, so I'm hoping it's just the Rails version. But if it's an issue purely with Rails 3.2.13 and has nothing to do with gems or other configuration, I'd have thought more people would have run into this...

Comment: so? you want more issues to link to? or what exactly are you trying to say? like this ie? https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9248

Comment: the answer link was the first I've seen of this issue occurring in a vacuum with only Rails creating the issue. Other links are like the one in your comment which deals with threadsafe mode (which afaik my app does not use). My point is that I'd expect more SO questions, Github issues, etc if it were purely Rails. I believe bumping the Rails version will get rid of the error, but I want to be sure we're catching the underlying issue - potentially [the Rails commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6ab1a9540b73555f2cabb54860b9ca17e8f226cb) linked to from your answer link

Comment: i really don't understand what your concern is. what else do you need to "answer" your question?

Comment: We've upgraded to Rails 4 and haven't seen this issue in over a month. Answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

Odd...

Try replacing this

```
<a href="<%= root_path %>" class="nav-link"><%= image_tag "image.svg", onerror: "this.src='image.png'" %></a>
```

with this

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("image.svg", onerror: "this.src='image.png'"), root_path, class: "nav-link") %>
```

Comment: unfortunately the markup has little to do with this... this issue appears on all pages regardless of the HTML/Ruby that generates the links (and the `link_to` syntax is used on other pages and still throws the error). I doubt that particular line can tell us very much about the problem.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that particular link was causing the error or not. Very odd... Sorry I couldn't help.